# Подскажите плз.....class path resource [ application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста куда положить файл application.properties что бы его было видно. Перепробовал всё, выдает  Failed to parse configuration class [company.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
Очевидно какая то проблема с фолдер страктчер.
Это MVC клиент который посылает REST запросы другому REST API.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("company")
@PropertySource({"classpath: application.properties"})

public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл должен лежать в **src/main/resources**. При объявлении в PropertySource нужно убрать пробел, чтобы получилось

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
```

Comment: СПАСИБО. пробел был лишним